# Unix what is /dev/cua* device ? and what is it used for?

Tags: unix

I want to know what are the devices /dev/cua* used for ? and what does "Cua" stand for ?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Open BSD Device Drivers Manual](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-5.7/cua.4).

"For hardware terminal ports, dial-out is supported through matching device nodes called calling units. For instance, the terminal called /dev/tty03 would have a matching calling unit called /dev/cua03."